# Proving that $3|x^2 \implies 3|x$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given a positive integer $x$, I would like to show that $3|x^2 \implies 3|x$. This is my missing step in the proof that $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational. My thoughts so far:

Assuming $3|x^2,$ then since $3$ is a prime number, we have that the prime factorization of $x^2$ is $m3^n$, where $n\geq 1$ and $\gcd(m,3) = 1.$ Then it follows that the prime factorization of $x$ is $r3^{n/2},$ where $\gcd(r,3) = 1$. I now want to show that $n$ must be even, so I can try to assume $n$ is odd and derive a contradiction...just not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Have you heard of Euclid's Lemma (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid's_lemma)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is by contradiction, assume $3\not |x$ then there are $a,b$ such that 
$$3a+bx=1$$
 now multiply by $x$ to get 
$$3xa+bx^2=x$$ and $3$ divides the left by assumption so it divides the right contradiction.

Comment: I agree I was about to edit.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started: suppose $x$ contains $n'$ factors of $3$, then how many factors of $3$ does $x^2$ contain? (I don't want to deprive you of the fun of working the rest out yourself :-P)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we are allowed to let the prime factorization of $x$ be $x =p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k \Rightarrow x^2 = p_1^2 p_2^2 \cdots p_k^2$. Since $3|x^2$ we have that $p_i=3$ (for some $1 \leq i \leq k$). But that means $3|x$ as well because the same $p_i$ is in the factorization of $x$ too

Comment: You are implcitly using *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. For the proof to be complete/correct you need to make that *explicit*.

Comment: Can you suggest how that can done? Thanks.

Comment: I imagine he is asking you to state that "Due to unique prime factorization, we know" etc$\dots$

Comment: Please explain how you deduced $\,3\mid (p_1\cdots p_k)^2\Rightarrow\, $ some $\,p_i = 3.\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: If $3 \mid (p_1\cdots p_k)^2$ then we know that $(p_1\cdots p_k)^2/3$ is some integer. And the only way that can happen is if there is a $3$ somewhere in $(p_1\cdots p_k)^3$ (that cancels out with the three in denominator) which means some $p_i=3$. Do you see any flaw in the reasoning there?

Comment: That's not a rigorous argument. Are you familiar with the *uniqueness* of prime factorizations, or Euclid's Lemma?

Comment: I am familiar with both, and the first one is what I used here.

Comment: @Sheheryar Then you should *explicitly* mention how you used it because, not too infrequently, students write such arguments thinking that no justification is needed, e.g. that is is "obvious", wrongly believing that neither FTA nor related results are needed. Without further elaboration, there is no way to know which argument was intended, the correct one, or the incorrect one.

Comment: I see, I have edited my answer and added that, thanks a lot for mentioning that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer I just thought of, using the lemma from number theory that if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $\gcd(a,c) = 1$ then $\gcd(a, bc) = 1.$

Using the above lemma, if $\gcd(3,x) = 1$, then $\gcd(3, x^2) = 1.$ Then by the contrapositive, if $\gcd(3, x^2) \neq 1,$ then $\gcd(3, x) \neq 1.$ But since $3$ is prime, we can reword that assertion as $3|x^2 \implies 3|x.$

Answer (score 0):

Your original post basically does it!
When you get to 
$$x = r3^{n/2}$$

and you know that $x, r$ and $n$ are integers, it follows that $\frac{n}{2}$ is an integer too. Hence $\frac{n}{2} = k$, for some integer $k$ and $n = 2k$, so $n$ is even.